# CSS Grid resize boxes

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to this forum and quite new to HTML and CSS.

CSS Grid is something I've found out about very recently and I am in love. It's so easy to use. However, there is one thing I can't seem to get right.

My problem is, as you can see I've added a header image. When I do add an image all of the boxes are the same height as the header. And that's what I don't want.

Yes, I can use `justify-self: center;` and `align-self: center;` but that doesn't solve the problem (I was gonna post a couple more pics with this code added but as I don't have more than 10 rep I can't post more than 2 links. I hope you can still understand how this doesn't solve the issue).

Does anyone know how I can keep the image and still resize the individual boxes to be what ever size I want and not just follow the size of the biggest box on the grid.

Thank you for the help. I appreciate it.

The following is a snipped of the code I have tried:

```css
body{
  background-color: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.container div:nth-child(even){
  background-color: #999999;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #727170;
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  ". header header ."
  ". nav nav ."
  ". content sidebar ."
  ". footer footer .";
}

.header{
  grid-area: header;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.nav{
  grid-area: nav;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.content{
  grid-area: content;
}

.sidebar{
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.footer{
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="header">
        <img src="./img/header.jpg"</img>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>

      <div class="content">Content</div>

      <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>

      <div class="footer">Copyright &copy 2017</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you paste your code using snippets? You can edit your post and paste code into corresponding fields to easier help. We will see not only code, but also the result and we will be able to solve it faster.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I think I did it right. Let me know if there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using `fr` that means that the whole space is divided in specified number **with equal sizing**(if it's columns - width, rows - height). You need just specify proper size for your row with header, or other rows.

Comment: Right ok. I understand what you mean. But how would that work code-wise if I use `grid-template-areas: `. Could I just put `grid-template-columns: auto auto  auto  auto;` instead of `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;`?

Comment: You can try. It's the best way to workout the problem. Also there is a `repeat()` which helps to provide few identical values.

Comment: I appreciate that. It was as simple as that. Very helpful. Thank you.